# Filemaker Pro Executesql returns empty with multiple sum value

Tags: filemaker

I am using Filemaker pro 14. Now working on dynamic charting of my months performance by using executesql, order by Months.

I use "Let" function to SELECT SUM for two separate fields.

Then I get result of two sets delimited data like below.

My problem is I cannot return a set of delimited data by direct dividing the two set of data?

For example:

```
List1: 100;150;200
List2: 1000;1200;1500
```

Desired Result:

```
List3: List1/List2 ==> 0.1;0.125;0.133
```

Actual Result (returned only one result):

```
List3: 0.0010013818
```

It seems that divided by data all connected together like

```
100150200/100012001500
```

Any advise is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The result you’re getting is actually expected behavior. As you discovered yourself, when you tell FileMaker to divide List1 by List2, it’s casting each list as a number and then dividing. This drops out all non-numeric characters and creates two long strings, then divides the first by the second.

Are you using FileMaker Pro Advanced? If so, the easiest way to fix this would be by using a custom function such as this:

```
/*
=======================================================
    MathLists ©2017 Drakeling Technologies
    Created by Jeff Drake 19 Oct 2017

    Parameters: list1 ; list2 ; separator

    Purpose: applies the specified operator to each value in list 1 and the corresponding value in list 2, e.g.
     MathLists ( "100;150;200" ; "1000;1200;1500" ; "/" ; ";" ) = ".1;.125;.1333333333333333"

    Dependencies: none
=======================================================
*/


Let ( [
         //CHANGE EACH LIST TO RETURN-DELIMITED.
         #list1 = Substitute ( list1 ; separator ; ¶ ) ;
         #list2 = Substitute ( list2 ; separator ; ¶ ) ;

         //STORE THE MAXIMUM NUMBER OF VALUES TO PROCESS.
         #maxValues = Max ( ValueCount ( #list1 ) ; ValueCount ( #list2 ) ) ;

         //STORE THE ORIGINAL SEPARATOR.
         $ƒMathLists = If ( IsEmpty ( $ƒMathLists ) ; separator ; $ƒMathLists )

] ; //end define Let

   Substitute (

      List (

         //IF THERE IS AT LEAST ONE PAIR OF VALUES REMAINING, RECURSE THE FUNCTION.
         If ( #maxValues > 1 ;
              MathLists ( LeftValues ( #list1 ; #maxValues - 1 ) ; LeftValues ( #list2 ; #maxValues - 1 ) ; operator ; $ƒDivideLists ) ) ; //end If

         //PERFORM THE MATHEMATICAL OPERATION ON THE nth VALUE FROM EACH LIST.
         Evaluate ( GetValue ( #list1 ; #maxValues ) & operator & GetValue ( #list2 ; #maxValues ) )

      ) //end List

      //RESTORE THE ORIGINAL SEPARATOR WHEN DONE.
      ; ¶ ; $ƒMathLists

   ) //end Substitute

   //CLEAR THE ORIGINAL SEPARATOR WHEN DONE.
   & Let ( $ƒMathLists = "" ; "" )

) //end Let
```

I’ve made the code extensible, so you can add, subtract, multiply, or divide, depending on which of the four operators you specify.

Hope that helps!